# XMLProvider and issue with DateTime

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm trying to use the XMLProvider to work with a file that uses the [AEOI XML format](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/foreign-account-tax-compliance-act-schema-and-supporting-documents) for exchange of tax information.

I'm generating the type from the .xsd file and the relevant bit is:

```
    <xs:element name="XMLTimeStamp" type="xs:dateTime" id="S1.2">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Date and time that the XML was originally created.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
```

And then in the XML file I have:

```
<XMLTimeStamp>2022-04-28T10:09:17</XMLTimeStamp>
```

The provider gets created and used like this:

```
    type CrsReport = XmlProvider<Schema="X:\\x\\uk_aeoi_submission_v2.0.xsd", 
                                    ResolutionFolder="X:\\x">
    let sample = CrsReport.Load("X:\\x\\9999999999SAMPLE_FILE.xml")
    let ts = sample.MessageData.XmlTimeStamp
```

However when I try and access the element in question I get this error:

```
Installed Packages
Fsharp.Data, 4.2.8
Error: System.Exception: Expecting DateTimeOffset in Value, got 2022-04-28T10:09:17
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfModule.PrintFormatToStringThenFail@1439.Invoke(String message) in D:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\printf.fs:line 1439
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.DispatchTailCalls(IntPtr callersRetAddrSlot, IntPtr callTarget, IntPtr retVal)
   at FSharp.Data.Runtime.TextRuntime.GetNonOptionalValue[T](String name, FSharpOption`1 opt, FSharpOption`1 originalValue)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0029>.$FSI_0029.main@()
```

So it looks as if type provider is expecting a DateTimeOffset instead of a DateTime and if I use a sample of XML to generate the provider it correctly identifies the element of the file as a DateTime.

Is this a bug with the provider or am I missing something about how to access or specify these elements?

Having spent some time reading the FSharp.Data code it looks as if it is a deliberate decision to use DateTimeOffset for xs:dateTime values.  The value given should parse to either a DateTime or a DateTimeOffset so something must be going on in the conversion process.

Comment: This is certainly a deliberate decision - the XML type provider maps `xs:datetime` to `DateTimeOffset` and `xs:date`  to `DateTime` (as per .NET guidelines to use `DateTimeOffset` for representing date with time). It seems that the code to actually parse string into `DateTimeOffset` is pretty elaborate: https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data/blob/166fa5a22d2228441dd444c571f8661085c38474/src/CommonRuntime/TextConversions.fs#L105 If you call `TextConversions.AsDateTimeOffset` on the kind of strings you have in your data, does that fail?

Comment: @TomasPetricek - I've traced through AsDateTimeOffset and it looks like a bug to me.  It's trying to insist that the DateTime.Kind is set - even though DateTimeOffset seems to discard this information.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the `AsDateTimeOffset` function in the TextConversions.fs.

The code is currently as shown below:

```
  let ParseISO8601FormattedDateTime text cultureInfo =
    match DateTime.TryParse(text, cultureInfo, dateTimeStyles) with
    | true, d -> d |> Some
    | false, _ -> None

  match ParseISO8601FormattedDateTime text cultureInfo with
  | Some d when d.Kind <> DateTimeKind.Unspecified -> 
    match DateTimeOffset.TryParse(text, cultureInfo, dateTimeStyles) with
    | true, dto -> dto |> Some
    | false, _ -> None
  | _ -> None
```

So what is happening is that when the date is `2022-04-28T10:09:17` them `d.Kind` is set to DateTimeKind.Unspecified and the code returns `None`.  Changing the date `2022-04-28T10:09:17Z` causes the `d.Kind` to be set and the date gets returned correctly. (So I have a work around for now)

I think that the current code might be over complicating things, it parses the date string twice and I don't see why it needs to worry about `d.Kind` being set or not.  My suggestion for this part of the code would be:

```
  match ParseISO8601FormattedDateTime text cultureInfo with
  | Some d -> new DateTimeOffset(d) |> Some
  | _ -> None
```

I did consider doing something like the xs:date conversion does which is to set the Kind to local.

```
  // Parse ISO 8601 format, fixing time zone if needed
  match ParseISO8601FormattedDateTime text cultureInfo with
  | Some d when d.Kind = DateTimeKind.Unspecified -> new DateTime(d.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Local) |> Some
  | x -> x
```

So for `asDateTimeOffset` this would then be

```
  match ParseISO8601FormattedDateTime text cultureInfo with
  | Some d when d.Kind = DateTimeKind.Unspecified ->
            let d1 = new DateTime(d.Ticks,DateTimeKind.Local)
            new DateTimeOffset(d1) |> Some
  | Some d -> new DateTimeOffset(d) |> Some
  | _ -> None
```

This doesn't set the `Kind` in the DateTime internals of the DateTimeOffset, but then DateTimeOffset is designed to:

> defines the difference between the current DateTimeOffset instance's
> date and time and Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)

So the offset encodes this information.